# Elasticsearch - are Completion Suggesters fast than EdgeNGram for product catalogues

Tags: java, angular, elasticsearch

I am currently implementing a search for a product catalogue with several thousand articles. Therefore, I would like to know if Completion Suggesters are the best way to implement this functionality as currently we are still using EdgeNGram. What would you suggest?

Comment: It depends on what you're after. In terms of functionality, completion suggesters are similar to match phrase, in that the matching of the tokens is **ordered**. Maybe explain your use case in more details so we'll be better able to suggest what feature would suit best. Performance only comes next.

Comment: Basically, a customer can search for an article on the front page in a search bar - as he types, possible products should show up, e.g. customer searches iph - iphone 14 / iphone 13 should appear as suggestions which then can be selected